# Distance from the intersection point of two circles to a certain point on the circumference of the greater circle

Tags: geometry, circles

On line segment $AB$ whose length is $6$, we take $AC = 3$ and $DB = 4$. Two circles are drawn taking $A$ and $B$ and centres and $AC$ and $BD$ as radii respectively. The circles intersect at points $P$ and $Q$. We join $A$ and $P$, and extend $AP$ so that it meets the circumference of the greater circle at $E$. How would one then find the length of $PE$?

[image: Figure]

Comment: Do you know intersecting secants theorem? Try to use it.

Comment: @cosmo5 thank you, i looked it up and that helped solve the problem! and i learnt a new theorem too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continue the line $AB$ till the second  intersection with the greater circle. Let the new intersection point be $F$.

By the [power of a point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) we have:
$$
AP\cdot AE=AD\cdot AF
$$
Can you take it from here?

> $$PE=\frac{AD\cdot AF}{AP}-AP=\frac{2\cdot10}{3}-3=\frac{11}3.$$